# smtp server has error and no mails are sending

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

There is simple contact us form i want to submit that form to specific mail id, i am using smtp for this but i have not receiving any mails.

i have installed wordpress and then added contact form 7 plugin that plugin gives no error but mail is not delivering

i have tried on following website also for testing my smtp server https://www.smtper.net/

but in that website i am receiving following error

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: relay not permitted
```

the problem is in smtp server but i am not able to solve it

Comment: post your code what you have tried

Comment: The question relates to smpter.net and should be addressed to site technical support. To send mails from your site, you can use any smtp plugin like WP Mail SMTP by WPForms: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/blastex and send emails without local smtp server from wp_mail function!

```
< ?php
$to = 'hello@emal.com, hello@boom.com';
$subject 'Hello from email client';
$html = 'Hello message from smtp !!!

Message from wordpress plugin!

';

// Install and activate plugin and send emails
$ok = wp_mail($to, $subject, $html);

// Show error
echo get_option('blastex_error');

?>
```